# Cursor always moves at last position

Tags: jquery, html, cursor, meiomask

I am using this [meiomask](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/) for entering time in my website:

Here is my code:

**HTML Markup:**

```
<input type="text" id="timepick" alt="time" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#timepick').setMask();
```

***Problem:***

Every time I enter time and trying to move cursor left or right, it sets to end and doesn't allow me to edit the time.

***Note***: In its website its working fine

*See Screenshot:*

[image]

I am also including these script files in my page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Widgets/AutoComplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Widgets/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Widgets/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Widgets/jquery.meio.mask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

*Browser I am using: GOOGLE CHROME 28*

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sRyPk/2/)

How can I move cursor left right and edit the time? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is a bug of meiomask plugin.
It doesn't recognize Chrome (and IE11) browser. (It happens in `_onPaste` function called by `_onKeyUp`)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this behaviour, maybe it is another Javascript on your site causing this problem? I've made a JSFiddle with your settings:

### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="timepick" alt="time" value="21:39" />
```

### jQuery

```
$('#timepick').setMask();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sRyPk/)

You should provide some more Infos:

- Operation System
- Browser
- Other JS Libraries
- etc.

Comment: Your fiddle gives an error, did you check browser console? i was also trying to reproduce this issue on fiddle but this external resource isn't working on fiddle. and FYI if we type 4 digits it will automatically separates it, see web site i mentioned in question

Comment: I'm using FF22 and getting no errors on that fiddle. And actually it's a working demo. I just set a value do reproduce you cursor behaviour but can't reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry pal, i din't check in FF, it's working fine in my FF, wonder why its not working in chrome :(